# How to write a script that searches for numeric pattern in huge file?

Tags: bash, join, awk

I have 200000 integers written in a file like this

```
0
1
2
3
.
98
99
.
.
100
101
102
.
```

I want to write with `awk` or `join` script that would tell how many times this pattern(from 0 to 99 )repeats itself.

Comment: Do you define the pattern beforehand?

Comment: @RobbieAverill Yes,pattern is 0,1,...,99.100 integers!

Comment: @andlrc Gives me 2000,not the right answer in my case.

Comment: i don't understand the question :-(, your sequence seems to be sorted as your example shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not battle tested:

```
awk 'i++!=$0{i=$0==0?1:0}i==100{c++;i=0}END{print c}' p.txt
```

Breakdown:

```
i++ != $0 {    # Use a cursor (i) which will be compared to input
  i=$0==0?1:0; # If not matched reset cursor if current line is zero then set to 1 because
               # .. this means we already matched our first line. If not set to 0
i == 100 {     # If Full pattern found:
  c++;         # add to count
  i=0;         # reset cursor
}
END {print c}  # Print matched count
```

Comment: @andrlrc
As I pointed out,this does not work for me.Will edit my question.

Comment: @RichardRublev This is another one liner than the one posted as comment

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a state variable which is reset anytime the pattern is incomplete.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    state = -1;
    count = 0;
}

/^[0-9]+$/ {
    if ( $0 == ( state + 1 ) || $0 == 0 ) {
        state = $0;
        if ( state == 99 ) {
            count++;
        }
    } else { 
        state = -1;
    }
    next;
}

    { state = -1; next; }

END {   
    print count;
}
```

This script assumes `awk` is in `/usr/bin` (the usual case).  You would put the script in a file, e.g., "patterns", and run it like

```
./patterns < p.txt
```

Comment: But how to load my file,or how to apply to p.txt?